# How to expand edges of an image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d

I'm working on a couple of maps for a 3D mesh. I need to expand the edges of an image in a way the image data itself is replicated as well.

Example:

[image: Expanded map edges example]

*(Image courtesy of [this post](http://forums.cgsociety.org/showthread.php?t=371730))*

I had some success using the `Content-Aware` Fill, but it's not perfect because it's way too *smart*. The edge pixels aren't replicated, they're sort of smoothly blended together and end looking lighter than the edge. They need to be of the same color of the edge.

[image: Content-Aware step 2]

How can I achieve a closer result to the top image in Photoshop?

Comment: Have you discovered any way to do this?

Comment: @calbar I don't think I got the action lying around anymore to double-check it, but I think I went with my comment on the answer below, an action that contracted the edge and executed the minimum filter 1px at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Select the blank area.

Menu>>select>>modify>>expand: 1 pixel (or two).

Menu>>filter>>other>>minimum: play with the values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this filter produces very strange results when using high radius values, and the extended edges don't match the image edges. However, you gave me an idea that might work well: Automate the act of selecting the negative space, expanding 1px, using `Minimum` with 1px radius. Repeat this a couple of times and and accurate edge is created.